# babel-node no longer working in different directory

Tags: node.js, babeljs

```
import credentials from '../config/credentials'
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Yesterday babel-node was working fine. Today, in my testing directory, it no longer works. Oddly enough, it runs my app which uses ES6 no problem.

Version: 5.6.14

No idea what's causing this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the following `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "stage": 0,
  "ignore": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "testing",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

Which disallowed babel-node from working in the testing directory.