# How to set a .rc file conditionally

Tags: shell, heroku, babeljs, rc

I am using `babel` and have a `.babelrc` file for its configuration:

```
{
  "stage": 0,
  "ignore": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "testing",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

However, when I'm developing locally, having this `.babelrc` file disallows me from running Babel's CLI `babel-node` in the `testing` folder (see: [babel-node no longer working in different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787011/babel-node-no-longer-working-in-different-directory) )

That said, when I push to Heroku, I need this configuration because I need to make sure the testing folder isn't compiled.

How can I conditionally set a `.babelrc` file that doesn't involve me having to remember to switch it back to the production version everytime I want to push to Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

You can set conditional things using the `env` option in your `.babelrc`

from [their docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#env-option):

```
{
  "stage": 0,
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "testing",
        "test"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "NODE_ENV=production node index.js",
  "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node index.js"
}
```

it checks BABEL_ENV, then NODE_ENV